# On reloading page redirects to Login page although url path remains unchanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, when logged in and entered to landing page works fine but, on reloading redirects to login page  keeping url unchanged. Please refer code below

This is the routing structure

```
<Routes>
      <Route path={home} element={<Navigate to={companyPage} />} />
      <Route
        path={companyPage}
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <CompanyPage />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        }
      />
      <Route path="*" element={<RouteNotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

ProtectedRoute.js (Here the routes are protected)

```
function ProtectedRoute({ children }) {
  const { authorized } = useContext(AutorizationContext);

  return authorized === true ? children : <Navigate to={RouteConstant.sign} />;
}

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};
```

What could be the best optimal solution? Any suggestions highly appreciated

Enter name and password both as 'test'

Comment: in your `app.js` file, you render `<Login/>` component instead of navigate to login route. that's why the url doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your state variable `authorized` is switching from true to false on page refresh
one solution would be using `localStorage` to store `authorized` value in a temporary variable

the `useLocalStorage` hook :

```
// file path : /src/use-local-storage.js

import { useState } from "react";

function UseLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
      return initialValue;
    }
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });

  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}

export default UseLocalStorage;
```

and in your `App.js` try this :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import AutorizationContext from "./context/auth-context";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import HomePage from "./pages/home/HomePage";
import UseLocalStorage from "./use-local-storage";

export default function App() {
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(false);
  const value = { authorized, setAuthorized };
  const [savedAuth, setSavedAuth] = UseLocalStorage();

  useEffect(() => {
    setAuthorized(savedAuth);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSavedAuth(authorized);
  }, [authorized, setSavedAuth]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AutorizationContext.Provider value={value}>
        {!authorized ? <Login /> : <HomePage />}
      </AutorizationContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

full sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-montalcini-d726m0?file=/src/App.js:0-832)

Comment: On reloading its redirecting to Login page again

Comment: I have just checked the sandbox link again, It is not redirecting on page refresh. have you tried to implement the code in the answer? cheers

Comment: Yes got it... not getting redirected.... Thanks